# Pull latest version of package from git

Tags: git, haskell-stack

I am using Haskell Stack, and the source code for the package I am building is on git. My `stack.yaml` looks like this:

```
packages:
- location:
    git: git@github.com:mhwombat/blah-blah-blah.git
    commit: master
. . .
```

Everything builds fine. However, suppose the source code is updated in the repository. Stack doesn't fetch the latest version; it continues to use the version it already has. My solution so far is to delete `.stack-work` and do another `stack build`, but of course it has to rebuild everything. When you're using lens, that takes a loooong time.

**Is there a way to force Stack to fetch the latest version from git?**

Already tried `stack update` and `stack clean`, but they don't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's one way, but it is tedious instead of master as the commit, place the SHA1 of the latest commit. You can get the latest commit by running:

```
git rev-parse origin/master
```

The output should look like this: ***de7059a7a7c81c9c8997cad6dce7cdbd5b6c09d9***

Then in your stack.yaml you would place this:

```
packages:
- location:
    git: git@github.com:mhwombat/blah-blah-blah.git
    commit: de7059a7a7c81c9c8997cad6dce7cdbd5b6c09d9
. . .
```

And you would have "*forced*" stack to fetch the latest commit when you run `stack build` no need to delete `.stack-work` anymore. It's not as simple as a single command but it worked for me and was not too annoying, as a bonus for me it helped me freeze a dependency. This is scriptable since it only uses git, though  it wasn't tiresome enough that I made a script.